# Disabling Page Item on page load/enable on page submit

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 2 page items (both a super lov from skillbuiders) which should be disabled when the page loads and then re-enabled once you submit. Following the guides i found via google, i created 2 dynamic events: 
one which gets triggered on 'page load', the second gets triggered once you press the 'Save' button. Both execute javascript:

```
Disable:
$('#P1225_PROJECT_ID').apex_super_lov('disable')
$('#P1225_JOB_ID').apex_super_lov('disable')

Enable:
$('#P1225_PROJECT_ID').apex_super_lov('enable')
$('#P1225_JOB_ID').apex_super_lov('enable')
```

The problem is they do not get disabled... If i execute the javascript from Firebug it does what i want it to.

I use apex 4.2, there are no conditions on the dynamic actions...

So the questions are, is there something obvious i do wrong? and is it possible to execute javascript without dynamic events?

Tks in advance!
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

When you make an submit the page is reloaded (load event) so your lov will remain disable.
Try other type of trigger for enable the lov.

Best Regards,

Iulian

Answer (score 0):

You can also create and execute javascript functions from  **HTML Header Attribute** of the apex page.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/bldapp_js.htm#HTMDB28451